# Google Apps Script - Setting revision history

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Has anyone worked with versioning on Google Sheets or Docs? I want a specific version of Google Sheets to be loaded when I or another user opens the sheet, this Id will be listed using the script below, but, I cannot find a way to set this as the version to load on opening the sheet. The opening of the sheet will be the trigger for this script to load.

See my script below

While I have reviewed https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions

I am unsure how to get it to set a specific version of the sheet on opening the sheet. I have attached my sample that is giving me an error: Invalid number of arguments provided. Expected 3-4 only (line 21, file "Code")

The methods available are:
delete
get
list
patch
update
There is no option to set a revision, so I am playing with the patch and update methods with little success. Any ideas?

Here's what I have so far:

```
function setRevisions() {
  listRevisions("1rMy631GhjrfaSlcRhUoICD4dYxNTBVJMwCzteGwl2wo")
}

function listRevisions(fileId) {
  var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId);
  if (revisions.items && revisions.items.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < revisions.items.length; i++) {
      var revision = revisions.items[i];
      Logger.log(revision.id);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No revisions found.');
  }
  if(revision.id = '18') {
  Drive.Revisions.patch(revision.id);
} else {
  Logger.log("18 is not available");
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

First obtain the revision Ids using [Drive.Revisions.list(fileId)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive#listing_revisions). After obtaining the differevent revision Ids, use the regular Revision methods like Drive.Revisions.get and  Drive.Revisions.update through [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive).

A demo sample can be found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860816/how-to-set-revision-history-with-google-apps-script):

```
function listRevisions(fileId) {
  var fileId = '1yck2UQDJztdqD3Ji8UT3KcwTKiA0bgLd2-4xqwbU824';
  var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId);

  if (revisions.items && revisions.items.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < revisions.items.length; i++) {
      var revision = revisions.items[i];
      var date = new Date(revision.modifiedDate);
      Logger.log(revision.id);
    }
  } else {
   Logger.log('No revisions found.');
  }
}

function alterRevision(){
  var fileId = '1yck2UQDJztdqD3Ji8UT3KcwTKiA0bgLd2-4xqwbU824';
  var change = Drive.Revisions.get(fileId, 1306);
  var update = Drive.Revisions.update(change, fileId, 1306);
  Logger.log(update.id + update.modifiedDate);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I saw this post too. However, it is not pushing the version that I specify. I assume that the .update method should push the version of the file that I am looking for?

Comment: I have used the exact syntax above and the version of the file is not being set to 18 in my case, it still retains its latest version when I open the file. Is it even possible to set a specific version to  load when I open a sheet/doc? Thanks in advance